# String index out of range when writing in specific line in a Textfile

Tags: python, text-files

Why does it keeps giving me this error? I have this in my first method but it doesn't give me an error, but when I use the code in the 2nd method it continue giving me this error

This is my first method, it works well,

```
    def btn_English(self):
    answerKey = open("answerkeyEnglish", 'r')
    studentExam = open("studentExam", 'r')
    index = 0
    numCorrect = 0

    for answerLine, studentLine in zip(answerKey, studentExam):
        answer = answerLine.split()
        studentAnswer = studentLine.split()
        if studentAnswer != answer:
            print("You got question number", index + 1, "wrong\nThe correct answer was", answer, "but you answered",
                  studentAnswer)
            index += 1
        else:
            numCorrect += 1
            index += 1
    gradeAverage = int((numCorrect / 2) * 100)
    grade = numCorrect
    english = open('examResult','w')
    english.write(str(grade))
```

and this the second method, where it gives the error. in english.write(str(grade)[2]).

```
    def btn_Math(self):
    answerKey = open("answerkeyEnglish", 'r')
    studentExam = open("studentExam", 'r')
    index = 0
    numCorrect = 0

    for answerLine, studentLine in zip(answerKey, studentExam):
        answer = answerLine.split()
        studentAnswer = studentLine.split()
        if studentAnswer != answer:
            print("You got question number", index + 1, "wrong\nThe correct answer was", answer, "but you answered",
                  studentAnswer)
            index += 1
        else:
            numCorrect += 1
            index += 1
    gradeAverage = int((numCorrect / 2) * 100)
    grade = numCorrect
    english = open('examResult','r')
    english.write(str(grade)[2])
```

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error because in the first method it works well, but in the 2nd method it gives error?

Comment: Because a string does'nt accept index.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `english.write(str(grade)[2])`? What does the `[2]` represent to you? Also you open the file in read mode with `english = open('examResult','r')` but then try to write to it, that's going to fail.

Comment: what should I do? if I remove the string it gives this error ? write() argument must be str, not int.

Comment: I want to write in the 3 line of the textfile @AlexHall. Is my code there gonna work ?

Comment: I want to write in the specific line in the text file. And that is the 2nd problem whether I will use 'a' or 'w'?

Comment: @JeferP.Bulan See this for writing in the specific line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45187717/10625520

Comment: Obtain all the grades without writing anything to a file, then afterwards open the file once and write each grade, all in one go.

Comment: @AlexHall what approach or how can I do write each grade all in one go? sorry I'm new in programming.

Comment: `for grade in grades: resultFile.write(str(grade)+'\n')`

Comment: Thanks sir its much clearer now. @AlexHall what is the 'grades' variable in the code that you are given? and where should I put it? sorry I'm just little confused now.

Answer (score 0):

`str(grade)[2]` gives the third character of `str(grade)`, which only exists if `grade` is a number with 3 or more digits.

Comment: grade is only single digit, what should I do to make my code work ?

Comment: How can I write in specific line in a textfile? is .write(str(grade)[2]) gonna work or I nee to change something because the character that will be inputted is single digit?